# vb.net position dialog on mouse location

Tags: .net, winforms, location

I have an `datagridview.columnheadermouseclick` eventhandler
this one has `e as datagridviewcellmouseeventargs` however `e.location` doesn't give me the mouse location, which I hoped it would.

With that in mind I tried accomplishing this (I have set `StartPosition` property of `FormFilter` to `Manual`)

```
Private Sub filterclm(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DGV.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    Using filter As New FormFilter
        filter.Location = e.Location 'wrong location
        If filter.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
            ...
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

How should I get the real location of the mouse?

Comment: [From the UX exchange, some guidelines on positioning pop-up dialogs.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/12963/142096)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.location` in the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event handler will hold the location relative to the column cell.

If you want to show your new `FormFilter` form where the mouse cursor is, you can actually ignore it and use the static property [`Cursor.Position`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position?view=netframework-4.6).
It will give you the position relative to the whole screen, which is what you need in order to set the `Location` of a new form:

```
filter.Location = Cursor.Position
```